# Can't add my twig condition in my div's class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

here's my issue,
i got this class in my Twig html :

```
<h4 class="myAnswers">
```

in my jQuery i did this (my button name is showAnswer) :

```
   $('.showAnswer').on('click', revealAnswers)

function revealAnswers() {
    $('.myAnswers').addClass('{% if answer.Valid == true %} text-success {% else %} text-danger {% endif %}');
}
```

and here is the result in the html :

```
class="myAnswers {% if answer.Valid == true %} text-success else text-danger endif"
```

i tried to escape all problematics characters ( like {%\ ) but it doesn't work.

Someone got an idea?

Comment: you cannot mix JS (which is client-side) and twig (which is server-side), they are unaware of each other entirely.

Comment: i tried to put this in the .html.twig file :
[`code`]
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $('.showAnswer').on('click', revealAnswers);
         function revealAnswers() {
    $('.myAnswers').addClass('{% if answer.Valid == true %} text-success {% else %} text-danger {% endif %}');
}
});</script>
[`code`]
but it return me this error :runtime error, Variable "answer" does not exist.

Comment: Put the javascript inside your twig template not an external file

Comment: ok, i did this in my twig template ( nammed quiz_play.html.twig )
![mycodepicture](https://ibb.co/hCjy30r).
but it doesn t seem to work, maybe it s how i wrote it, im not used to write js or jquery inside script tags

Comment: Please update your question with the modified code, also don't the script in the for loop. Just place it above `</body>`